# Two-cardinal diamond principles and saturation of the nonstationary ideal

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

In the paper "Stationary reflection and the club filter", the author Masahiro Shioya says that the club filter on $P_{\omega_1}(\lambda)$ cannot be $2^\lambda$-saturated for $\lambda > \omega_1$, citing Shelah's book "Nonstructure Theory" (in preparation).  I have three questions:

1)  Is there a published reference for this result?

2) Does the theorem apply to $P_{\omega_1}(\lambda) | S$ for an arbitrary stationary set $S$?

3) Does the proof go through a two-cardinal diamond principle?  I.e., did Shelah prove (in ZFC) that $\lozenge_{\omega_1,\lambda}$ holds for $\lambda > \omega_1$?  What about $\lozenge_{\omega_1,\lambda}(S)$ for arbitrary stationary $S$?

I am particularly interested in the case $\lambda = 2^{\omega} = \omega_2$.  In this case $\lozenge_{\omega_1,\lambda}(S)$ was proved by Donder and Matet in the paper "Two cardinal versions of diamond" for stationary sets $S$ of the form $\lbrace a \in P_{\omega_1}(\lambda) : \sup a \in B\rbrace$ where $B \subset \lambda$ is a stationary set consisting of points of cofinality $\omega$.  Does this hold for arbitrary stationary $S$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across this, but probably you resolved this question long ago.  In any case, to address your questions in order as asked,

1) Shioya has an [article](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2449470) on this. Let me know if you'd like me to ask him for a pdf.

2) I believe the consistency of local $\lambda^+$-saturation of $NS_{\omega_1,\lambda}$ is still open for $\lambda > \omega_1$.

3) Yes, the proof does go through proving in ZFC $\Diamond_{\omega_1,\lambda}$ for all $\lambda > \omega_1$.